Android compose `NotificationListenerService.onNotificationPosted` is never called
I'm trying to add a notification listener to a Kotlin android compose project:
My AndroidManigest.xml:
    <application>
        <!-- ... -->
        <service
            android:name=".MyNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:foregroundServiceType="specialUse"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <property
                android:name="android.app.PROPERTY_SPECIAL_USE_FGS_SUBTYPE"
                android:value="explanation_for_special_use" />
        </service>

    </application>

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_SPECIAL_USE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

My MainActivity.kt:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var serviceIntent: Intent

    private fun isServiceRunningInForeground(): Boolean {
        val manager = this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        for (service in manager.getRunningServices(Int.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (MyNotificationListenerService::class.java.name == service.service.className) {
                if (service.foreground) {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        serviceIntent = Intent(this, MyNotificationListenerService::class.java)
        Log.d("NB", "MainActivity.onCreate")

        setContent {
            MyNotificationListenerTheme {
                var isServiceRunning by remember { mutableStateOf(isServiceRunningInForeground()) }

                Scaffold(
                    floatingActionButton = {
                        FloatingActionButton(
                            onClick = {
                                if (isServiceRunning) {
                                    stopService(serviceIntent)
                                } else {
                                    if (!NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages(this)
                                            .contains(
                                                packageName
                                            )
                                    ) {
                                        startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS))
                                    }

                                    startForegroundService(
                                        serviceIntent
                                    )
                                }
                                isServiceRunning = !isServiceRunning
                            }
                        ) {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = if (isServiceRunning) Icons.Default.Close else Icons.Default.PlayArrow,
                                contentDescription = if (isServiceRunning) "Pause" else "Play"
                            )
                        }
                    }
                ) { innerPadding ->
                    Surface(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                    ) {
                        // Your UI content
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

My MyNotificationListenerService.kt:
class MyNotificationListenerService : NotificationListenerService() {

    private val channelId = "MyNotificationListenerService"

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        createNotificationChannel()
        startForeground(1, getNotification(), ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_SPECIAL_USE)
        Log.d("NB", "MyNotificationListenerService.onCreate")
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d("NB", "MyNotificationListenerService.onStartCommand")
        return START_STICKY
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(
            channelId,
            "My Notification Listener Service Channel",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )
        val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
    }

    private fun getNotification(): Notification {
        return Notification.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setContentTitle("Running...")
            .build()
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        Log.d("NB", "MyNotificationListenerService.onBind")
        return super.onBind(intent)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        Log.d("NB", "MyNotificationListenerService.onDestroy")
        return super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        val text = sbn.notification?.extras?.getString("android.text");
        Log.d("NB", "MyNotificationListenerService.onNotificationPosted - text: $text")
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn)
    }

    override fun onNotificationRemoved(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        // Optionally handle notification removal
    }

    override fun onListenerConnected() {
        Log.d("NB", "MyNotificationListenerService.onListenerConnected")
    }
}

When I press "play" I do get the logs:
MainActivity.onCreate
MyNotificationListenerService.onCreate
MyNotificationListenerService.onStartCommand

But when my phone receives a notification, MyNotificationListenerService.onNotificationPosted is not called.
What am I missing?

That's not something that you start yourself. The user must manually enable your app as a listener, then your Service will be started automatically by the system. You can try to direct them to the relevant page in Settings, but they have to turn it on. You'll want to remove the foreground stuff, too. The system is handling the Service, so it can run in the background.

This is what the line startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS)) dos no? I already turned it on for my application

Ah, yeah, I see it now. Only noticed the foreground stuff at first. Remove the startForegroundService() and startForeground() calls you have for MyNotificationListenerService. The system will handle starting it after you enable it in Settings.

Just tried and you are right ! :o Thank you ! Do you want to write an answer so I can validate it ?

Excellent! I'm good, though. Nothin' huge. Please feel free to finish this up however you like. Thanks for the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

As suggested by Mike M. in the comments, this is not something you start yourself.
The user must manually enable your app as a listener, then your Service will be started automatically by the system.
It is possible to direct the user to the screen for them to enable it using startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS)).
Removing the logic to start the service and all the foreground related code made it work:
AndroidManifest.xml:
    <application>
        <!-- ... -->
        <service
            android:name=".MyNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />


MainActivity.kt:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            MyNotificationListenerTheme {
                var isServiceRunning by remember { mutableStateOf(isServiceRunningInForeground()) }

                Scaffold { innerPadding ->
                    Surface(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                    ) {
                        // Your UI content
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

MyNotificationListenerService.kt:
class MyNotificationListenerService : NotificationListenerService() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.d("NB", "MyNotificationListenerService.onCreate")
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d("NB", "MyNotificationListenerService.onStartCommand")
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        Log.d("NB", "MyNotificationListenerService.onBind")
        return super.onBind(intent)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        Log.d("NB", "MyNotificationListenerService.onDestroy")
        return super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        val text = sbn.notification?.extras?.getString("android.text");
        Log.d("NB", "MyNotificationListenerService.onNotificationPosted - text: $text")
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn)
    }

    override fun onNotificationRemoved(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        // Optionally handle notification removal
    }

    override fun onListenerConnected() {
        Log.d("NB", "MyNotificationListenerService.onListenerConnected")
    }
}

